# Minimal hitting set with respect to set inclusion from a book "Parameterized Complexity Theory"

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, np-hard, set-cover

In the first chapter of ["Parameterized Complexity Theory](https://books.google.de/books/about/Parameterized_Complexity_Theory.html?id=VfJz6hvFAjoC&redir_esc=y&hl=de)" by Flum and Grohe, an example is presented to find a hitting set of minimal cardinality.

In Fig. 1.3, the author says a black colored leaf is the minimal with respect to set inclusion and a hitting set consists of the vertices labeling the edges on the path from the root to the leaf. However, both grey and black colored hitting set consists of 3 vertices. Why grey colored leaf is not minimal in this case?

Related question: [Given a set of sets, find the smallest set(s) containing at least one element from each set](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/given-a-set-of-sets-find-the-smallest-sets-containing-at-least-one-element-fr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are confusing the terms minimal and minimum. The Hitting set problem is to find a hitting set of *minimum* cardinality, not a minimal set.

A set $S$ is called *minimal* with respect to some property (in this case, being a hitting set) if there exists no strict subset $T$ of $S$ (i.e. $T\subsetneq S$) that also satisfies that property.

On the other hand, a set $S$ is said to have *minimum* size or cardinality with respect to some property if there exists no set $T$ of strictly smaller size (i.e. $|T|< |S|$) that also satisfies this property.

A minimum size set must be minimal (why?), but a minimal set need not be of minimum size (why?).

In the example in the book, the set $\{b,c,d\}$ is not a minimal hitting set, because its strict subset $\{c,d\}$ is also a hitting set. The subset $\{b,d,f\}$ is a minimal hitting set, because it has no strict subset that is a hitting set. It is not a minimum hitting set, because there is a hitting set of size $2$ ($\{c,d\}$).

Comment: Thanks, I now understand.